# Renew SSL certificates with Certbot without unneeded domains

Tags: nginx, certbot

Currently my certbot fails to renew because one of the sub-domain is no longer valid: `unneededsubdomain.foo.co.uk` and `www.unneededsubdomain.foo.co.uk`.

This is because I have removed the domain record, as I no longer need it linked to this server. However, I still want to renew the certificates for all the other sub-domains like: `foo.co.uk` `www.foo.co.uk` and `api.foo.co.uk`.

This is how my output looks similar to when I run `certbot renew`:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/foo.co.uk-0001.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert not yet due for renewal

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/foo.co.uk.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for unneededsubdomain.foo.co.uk
http-01 challenge for www.unneededsubdomain.foo.co.uk
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Attempting to renew cert (foo.co.uk) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/foo.co.uk.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. www.unneededsubdomain.foo.co.uk (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from ... :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from .... Skipping.
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.co.uk/fullchain.pem (failure)

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

The following certs are not due for renewal yet:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.co.uk-0001/fullchain.pem expires on 2019-07-06 (skipped)
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.co.uk/fullchain.pem (failure)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.unneededsubdomain.foo.co.uk
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   ...

   Domain: unneededsubdomain.foo.co.uk
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   ...

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

As you can see, the renewal fails because it tries to renew a certificate that is no longer needed. How do I successfully renew my certificates without this unneeded subdomain?

(NOTE: foo.co.uk is of course not my actual site. I just replaced it with a dummy name)

Comment: So you can delete the domain from letsencrypt folders and it will not try again

Comment: Sorry I looked through quite a few folders and am not sure which folder you are referring to. Which folder is it that I need removed?

Comment: Sorry, the whole domain isn't bad just a few subdomains. In that case, just re-run the original cert process without those domains.